# How to generate a nupkg with all dlls of a csproj (including PackageReference and ProjectReference)?

Tags: c#, azure-devops, nuget-package

Was looking in having all dlls from the main project in one package instead of one package per dll/library/cs project. Basically, need to package the content of the bin folder of the main project. The package should not

- have dependencies as all are packed.
- have any file content
- be generated upon build

The need here is not having to pack for execution but to reference/use the code with LinqPad.

**Context**

Azure pipeline to build the package.
CS standard/sdk projects: Platform is composed of a main project, multiple project references and package references.

**Issue** How to achieve the goal as it's not obvious?

I've tried different approaches but I can't get it to pack only the dlls.

What tips would you share to do so?

Answer (score 0):

So after roaming the land of git/stackoveflow I came up with this

I tried adding this bit into the main project csproj, under `<Project Sdk="MSBuild.SDK.SystemWeb">`

```
<!-- Packaging for LPs -->
  <PropertyGroup>
    <PackageId>NAME OF THE PACKAGE TO GENERATE</PackageId>
    <Authors>THE AUTHOR</Authors>
    <Company>THE COMPANY NAME</Company>
    <GeneratePackageOnBuild>false</GeneratePackageOnBuild>
    <NuspecProperties>version=$(PackageVersion)</NuspecProperties>
    <SuppressDependenciesWhenPacking>true</SuppressDependenciesWhenPacking>
    <IncludeContentInPack>false</IncludeContentInPack>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetsForTfmSpecificBuildOutput>$(TargetsForTfmSpecificBuildOutput);GetTheFiles</TargetsForTfmSpecificBuildOutput>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <Target DependsOnTargets="ResolveReferences" Name="GetTheFiles">
    <ItemGroup>
      <BuildOutputInPackage Include="$(OutputPath)\*.dll">
      </BuildOutputInPackage>
    </ItemGroup>
  </Target>
```

In azure CI Pipeline, I created a new build including these tasks

**Task 1** - Use NuGet to restore the solution (.sln)

**Task 2** - Use Powershell to set the build number with the variables declared on the CI Write-Host "##vso[build.updatebuildnumber]$(AssemblyBuildNumber).$(AssemblyMajorVersion).$(AssemblyMinorVersion).$(AssemblyRevisionNumber)"  This is important as it will initialize PackageVersion in version=$(PackageVersion). PackageVersion is a reserved property.

**Task 3** - Use Visual Studio build (VsBuild@1) to build and pack the main csproj

```
- task: VSBuild@1
  displayName: 'Name of the Task'
  inputs:
    solution: PathToProj/MySite.csproj
    msbuildArgs: '/p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true /t:pack /p:PackageVersion="$(Build.BuildNumber)" /p:BuildAuthorizer=$(Build.RequestedForEmail) /p:langversion=latest'
    platform: '$(BuildPlatform)'
    configuration: '$(BuildConfiguration)'
    maximumCpuCount: true
```

**Task 4** - Use .Net Core to push to Az Artifacts. Select the nuget push command.

Thoughts?